# Cannot find alsamixer and no sound on dualboot Ubuntu 16.04/Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a strange problem with my sound settings on Ubuntu.
I have sound on Windows 10 dualboot but if I would restart pc and boot into Ubuntu 16.04 there is no sound anymore.

I tried to get into alsamixer, but I get

> cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

I tried also with `alsamixer -c 1` but without luck.

It's interesting that if I turn off notebook and boot again in Ubuntu, the sound suddenly appears! (and alsamixer also).

I know that is something wrong in booting, did someone has the same problem or know what could I do to resolve this?